# Google Cloud Logging API / Service Details 100% Error Rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

When reviewing my Google Cloud Logging API / Service Details, I'm seeing 15,752,991 `google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2.WriteLogEntries` Requests in the past 30 days with 100% Error Rate. Also according to the Service Details Graph, these requests are all returning `403` Status Codes.

I tried to review the Logs in Log Explorer filtering by `http_request.status>400` but all I see is hundreds of requests with `404` or `502` Status Codes and all set with a Warning Severity. It seems all of these requests are coming from random unknown IP addresses. I imagine it's some kind of bot that is pinging our Cloud Function Webhooks looking for exploits. I'm OK to ignore this, but what I don't understand is there is no correlation between the Cloud Logging API / Service Details & Log Explorer.

What am I missing here? My goal is to address the API / Service Details 100% Error rate being reported, but the GCP console is not providing any details on how to address it.

Comment: IIUC your code is unable to write to Cloud Logging (unauthorized|403). This is possibly because the Service Account being used to write the logs (no longer) has correct authorization. An unfortunate consequence of this is that the logs aren't being created (in Cloud Logging) and so there's nothing for you to find. The request logs represent incoming requests (yes, likely bots and other bad actors) and these are written.

Comment: If the Logging service (`WriteLogEntries`) (which language are you using? Java?) is being called by the Cloud Functions then, you should look to the -- either default Compute or your custom -- Service Account policy to ensure it has permission to write logs ([roles](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control)) and, if that's OK, you may want to double check that the [Log Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#buckets) haven't been changed.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks so much! I'll review the service accounts, you may be right. I never considered this! I'll be sure to report back on the results. Thanks again. P.S. I'm using JavaScript on front-end and backend.

Comment: @DazWilkin you were spot on... a service account was missing the correct authorization. All set now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that it helped.